# Is there a way to make GNOME Terminal Read-only with shortcut?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 18, and GNOME Terminal 3.28.2 which has the menu option `Terminal -> Read-only` to prevent something being typed accidentally. Is there a keyboard shortcut to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can define one. Open Edit -> Preferences and select Shortcuts in the left bar. There you'll find it.

Notice, however, that the very same shortcut will also leave read-only mode. In other words, being in read-only mode disables the regular keypresses that would go to the terminal, but does not disable shortcuts.